Unable to invoke callback stored in an object
I created an in-memory notification service for use within my Dart/Flutter code bases. I started using the Observer pattern but quickly found that subscribing to changes in deeply nested view models became painful and convoluted.
The intent is to create a singleton service that can publish notifications in a strongly typed manner. Consumers can subscribe to targeted notifications and also receive the payload in a strongly typed manner.
I have two different notifications that I've written that effectively provide the same payload. The first one works and the 2nd one throws the following runtime error.
Unhandled exception:
type '(ExampleNotification) => void' is not a subtype of type '(PublishedNotification) => dynamic'
#0      NotificationService.publish (package:console/notification_service.dart:42:24)
#1      main (package:console/console.dart:15:23)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#3      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

Each Notification extends a base PublishedNotification class.
abstract class PublishedNotification {
  String qualifier;

  PublishedNotification(this.qualifier);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PublishedNotification{qualifier: $qualifier}';
  }
}

import 'package:console/published_notification.dart';

class HelloWorldNotification extends PublishedNotification {
  HelloWorldNotification() : super('Hello World Message');
}

import 'package:console/published_notification.dart';

class ExampleNotification extends PublishedNotification {
  ExampleNotification() : super('This is an example');
}

Each notification can be published by anything and only subscribers will receive the notification. When an object subscribes to a notification a subscription is created that contains the callback to invoke on the subscriber along with the Type of the notification the subscription is targeting.
import 'dart:mirrors';

import 'package:console/published_notification.dart';

class Subscription<T extends PublishedNotification> {
  final Function(T) subscriberCallback;
  Type targetNotification = reflectClass(T).reflectedType;

  Subscription(this.subscriberCallback);
}

Subscribing, publishing and unsubscribing is done via a NotificationService. Calling the subscribe method has the subscriber passing a callback that will be invoked each time the notification is published. It also returns the Subscription itself so the caller can unsubscribe and clean-up during disposal.
When publish is invoked it takes an argument that extends PublishedNotification. Some reflection is used to determine the type and then I pull all subscriptions out of the subscribers collection and invoke their callbacks with the notification.
import 'dart:mirrors';

import 'package:console/published_notification.dart';
import 'package:console/subscription.dart';

class NotificationService {
  // List of subscribers grouped by notification type.
  final Map<Type, List<Subscription>> subscriptions = <Type, List<Subscription>>{};

  // Subscribe to a notification.
  // notification is a required named parameter. 
  // A secondary 'condition' parameter will be added to support conditional pushing a notification to a subscriber based on if the condition passes or not.
  Subscription<T> subscribe<T extends PublishedNotification>({required Function(T payload) notification}) {
    // Wrap notification callback into a subscriber.
    final newSubscriber = Subscription(notification);

    ClassMirror notificationClass = reflectClass(T);
    Type notificationType = notificationClass.reflectedType;

    // Store the subscriber into our subscriptions collection.
    late List<Subscription> subscribers;
    if (subscriptions[notificationType] == null) {
      subscribers = List.empty(growable: true);
      subscriptions[notificationType] = subscribers;
    }

    subscribers.add(newSubscriber);

    // Return so that it can be provided during an unsubscribe request.
    return newSubscriber;
  }

  // Publish a notification to all subscribers
  void publish<T extends PublishedNotification>(T notification) {
    Type notificationType = notification.runtimeType;
    if (subscriptions[notificationType] == null) {
      return;
    }

    List<Subscription> subscribers = subscriptions[notificationType]!;

    // Invoke the callback delegate we have stored within each subscriber.
    for (Subscription targetSubscriber in subscribers) {
      targetSubscriber.subscriberCallback(notification);
    }
  }

  // Unsubscribe the
  void unsubscribe(Subscription subscriber) {
    subscriptions[subscriber.targetNotification]?.remove(subscriber);
  }
}

I have an example console Dart application that I created to reproduce the issue I'm seeing. I subscribe to two different notifications, publish the notifications and then unsubscribe. When the HelloWorldNotification is published my callback is invoked without any issues. When the ExampleNotification is published I receive the exception I show above.
import 'package:console/example_notification.dart';
import 'package:console/hello_world_notification.dart';
import 'package:console/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:console/published_notification.dart';
import 'package:console/subscription.dart';

void main() {
  var notificationService = NotificationService();
  Subscription helloWorldSubcription =
      notificationService.subscribe<HelloWorldNotification>(notification: handleHelloWorldNotification);
  Subscription exampleSubscription =
      notificationService.subscribe<ExampleNotification>(notification: handleExampleNotification);

  notificationService.publish(HelloWorldNotification());
  notificationService.publish(ExampleNotification());

  notificationService.unsubscribe(helloWorldSubcription);
  notificationService.unsubscribe(exampleSubscription);

  // These should not hit the handlers below.
  notificationService.publish(HelloWorldNotification());
  notificationService.publish(ExampleNotification());
}

void handleHelloWorldNotification(PublishedNotification payload) {
  print(payload.qualifier);
}

void handleExampleNotification(ExampleNotification payload) {
  print(payload.qualifier);
}

I don't understand why the first notification works fine and the second doesn't. They're both the same from an implementation perspective and the callbacks aren't any different. I'm assuming this is an issue with how I'm inferring the generics within the NotificationService but I'm not 100% sure why that's the case.
I can do a cast within my for-loop for each Subscription and the problem goes away and everything works as expected.
  // Publish a notification to all subscribers
  void publish<T extends PublishedNotification>(T notification) {
    Type notificationType = notification.runtimeType;
    if (subscriptions[notificationType] == null) {
      return;
    }

    List<Subscription> subscribers = subscriptions[notificationType]!;

    // Invoke the callback delegate we have stored within each subscriber.
    for (Subscription targetSubscriber in subscribers) {
      var s = targetSubscriber as Subscription<T>; // Cast here
      s.subscriberCallback(notification);
    }
  }

Is there something glaringly wrong with my implementation of the publish method and how I'm storing the subscription callbacks? I have the fix but I'm wanting to understand the reason why the first publish works and the 2nd doesn't unless I force a cast. Is a cast going to ultimately be required or is there a way to refactor a bit so the cast isn't needed?
Thanks!
Edit
Ok, so it seems that dart:mirrors isn't supported in Flutter. I had to go hunt for a different way to capture type information and discovered I actually don't need to use reflactClass. When I updated my NotificationService to remove the usage of dart:mirrors the exceptions stopped happening.
import 'dart:mirrors';

import 'package:console/published_notification.dart';
import 'package:console/subscription.dart';

class NotificationService {
  // List of subscribers grouped by notification type.
  final Map<Type, List<Subscription>> subscriptions = <Type, List<Subscription>>{};

  // Subscribe to a notification.
  @override
  Subscription<T> subscribe<T extends PublishedNotification>({required Function(T payload) notification}) {
    // Wrap notification callback into a subscriber.
    final newSubscriber = Subscription(notification);

    // Store the subscriber into our subscriptions collection.
    late List<Subscription> subscribers;
    if (subscriptions[T] == null) {
      subscribers = List.empty(growable: true);
      subscriptions[T] = subscribers;
    }

    subscribers.add(newSubscriber);

    // Return so that it can be provided during an unsubscribe request.
    return newSubscriber;
  }

  // Publish a notification to all subscribers
  @override
  void publish<T extends PublishedNotification>(T notification) {
    if (subscriptions[T] == null) {
      return;
    }

    List<Subscription> subscribers = subscriptions[T]!;

    // Invoke the callback delegate we have stored within each subscriber.
    for (Subscription targetSubscriber in subscribers) {
      targetSubscriber.notify(notification);
    }
  }

  // Unsubscribe the
  @override
  void unsubscribe(Subscription subscriber) {
    subscriptions[subscriber.targetNotification]?.remove(subscriber);
  }
}

This change was also applied to my Subscription class as well.
class Subscription<T extends PublishedNotification> {
  final Function(T) _subscriberCallback;
  Type targetNotification = T;

  Subscription(this._subscriberCallback);

  void notify(T notification) {
    _subscriberCallback(notification);
  }
}

I no longer need the cast and everything seems to work as expected. I'm still interested in understanding why reflectClass.reflectedType caused issues but just passing T directly into everything does not.

I'm not getting an exception when I try running your code.

Are you running it with or without the cast the I show at the bottom? I don't get an exception when I run with the cast, but I do without it.

Not seeing an exception with or without the as Subscription<T> cast.

Ok, I removed the cast and now it compiles as well. I had done some refactoring (and updated my post to reflect it). If I revert back to using Type targetClass = reflectClass(T).reflectedType rather than the newer way of accessing the Type it throws the exception. I'll revert my updated post to the original and then post an answer showing the removal of dart:mirrors usage solved for it. I'd like to know why dart:mirrors throws the exception though.

Ok @mmcdon20 - I reverted my post to the original so the exceptions now happen. I also edited it to show the changes I made (passing T everywhere instead of reflectClass(T).reflectedType and how that seemed to resolve the issue.

Looking at your code, the change between T and reflectClass(T).reflectedType, is not what fixed the problem, instead, you introduced a new function notify in your Subscription class, and that appears to be the change that stopped the exception from occurring.

In other words, targetSubscriber.subscriberCallback(notification);, causes the exception while targetSubscriber.notify(notification); does not. I am not entirely sure why at the moment.

Also, an unrelated issue, but your use of late within the subscribe function is not correct. This will cause an exception if you attempt to subscribe the same type twice. You probably want a nullable type instead.

Thanks for pointing that out. I went back and retested and see that as well now. I assume this is because when the callback is invoked it doesn't know what T is for some reason (despite being available on the publish method) whereas when I invoke the callback from within the notify method T is known. I think I would kind of get that to some degree if it wasn't for the fact that the first publish it can figure it out and the second publish it can't. Perhaps T is captured as HelloWorldNotification within that context at runtime and not released when the 2nd call comes around?

Well in the first example the callback is taking a PublishedNotification as an argument, while the second example is taking the more specific ExampleNotification. If you update the first callback to accept a HelloWorldNotification then neither work.

Ah, ok. I completely missed that my callbacks had a different signature. Thanks for pointing that out. I also replaced the usage of late with a null coalescing assignment operator - List<Subscription> subscribers = subscriptions[notificationType] ??= List.empty(growable: true);
So in the end it seems related to the fact that T is unknown when the callback is invoked from the publish method. Even if I change the code example code to include , like service.publish<ExampleNotification>(ExampleNotification()); it still seems unable to determine T in the publish method.

I think I figured out the issue. I'll post as an answer below.

Consider the following code:
class PublishedNotification {}
class Subscription<T extends PublishedNotification> {  }
class GenericClass<T> {}

void main() {
  print(GenericClass().runtimeType); // GenericClass<dynamic>
  print(Subscription().runtimeType); // Subscription<PublishedNotification>
}

As you can see above, since you have constrained the generic type with a T extends PublishedNotification clause, when you use a Subscription as a raw type it is now equivalent to Subscription<PublishedNotification> not Subscription<dynamic> as you might expect.
With that in mind, the following code
for (Subscription targetSubscriber in subscribers) {
  targetSubscriber.subscriberCallback(notification);
}

is really,
for (Subscription<PublishedNotification> targetSubscriber in subscribers) {
  targetSubscriber.subscriberCallback(notification);
}

And if you mouseover targetSubscriber in your editor it will tell you the type is Subscription<PublishedNotification>.
Now you are using the above with the following callbacks:
void handleHelloWorldNotification(PublishedNotification payload) {
  print(payload.qualifier);
}

void handleExampleNotification(ExampleNotification payload) {
  print(payload.qualifier);
}

With the first callback there is no issue, because the types match as PublishedNotification, but in the second callback you have a problem. A Subscription<PublishedNotification> should be able to use a callback on any PublishedNotification but the actual callback is restricted to only accepting ExampleNotification which is why the exception occurs.

Ah, this makes sense having seen it like this. So this boils down to a variance issue - with my usage of generics. That would explain why invoking notify on the Subscription class solves for this because T is explicitly the child class in that context. Thanks!
